# Cannot drag UIImageView from Mainstory board to ViewController

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, xcode13

I am unable to drag my UIImageView from Main.storyboard to ViewController. Even the blue line doesn't appear.

I've pressed the control button but this isn't working. Just nothing happens.

**See here**
[image: See here]

Can someone please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are new to Swift and iOS development. Firstly Check if your `UIViewController` in storyboard is correcly linked with your custom class which you call  `ViewController`. Do the following:

[image: pic1]

Check the linking if "ViewController" is set up in the class box:

[image]

If everything is set up properly then restart XCode.